# Apache: Sort directory listings alphabetically, case agnostically

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

How can I get Apache to sort directory listing file names alphabetically in a case agnostic manner?

Right now, this is what it looks like:

```
Abcd
Efgh
bddc
casd
```

This is what I want:

```
Abcd
bddc
casd
Efgh
```

Comment: Popular Question and not a single upvote :-(

Comment: Don't lose hope yet!

Answer (score 3):

Use `IgnoreCase` option. It described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

Comment: Oh thank you very very much! I swear I scoured that huge document for about 20 minutes but didn't see that section.

Comment: :) I'm glad it helped.